# Laravel database queue worker not processing jobs

Tags: database, laravel, queue, supervisord, laravel-queue

I'm using **laravel queue** using **database driver** and **supervisor process manager**.
Everything was good and jobs were being processed by queue worker. But at once I just noticed that jobs are not being processed anymore. Jobs are stuck in database and queue worker is not picking them up.
I have checked:

- Supervisor config is OK, queue worker runs by supervisor.
- Worker is now running too. In `htop` I can see it is running.
- Till now, 11984 jobs have been processed. And there are 1181 jobs in database.
- Jobs in database are same as jobs that have been processed.
- If I just kill worker process, supervisor will run it again and worker will start processing jobs. I have tried that. But after a while worker will stop working again.

I am using laravel 5.3.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when using laravel queue job processing, getting stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354331/when-using-laravel-queue-job-processing-getting-stuck)