# Laravel queue doesn't fail automatically despite using --tries

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

I'm want to queue some jobs using Redis,so I made an Event and its Listener.

The Listener implements ShouldQueue. I deliberately throw exception to test whether it fails. By entering the the command `php artisan queue:work --tries=3` it should try the job 3 times and if it can't be done, add it to failed-jobs right? but it doesn't do so. I tried using database driver but nothing changed.

One time I used `php artisan queue:work --tries=3 --daemon` despite the fact that `--daemon` is deprecated, and after 3 tries,the job was marked as failed - but when I stopped the command and ran it again, it didn't fail again.

why is this happening? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should deal with the failed jobs and check for the reasons ,
I suggest Adding Failed_jobs Table and check for failure reasons run theses commands to use that

```
php artisan queue:failed-table

php artisan migrate
```

Then try

```
php artisan queue:work redis --tries=3 --delay=3
```

If the job failed check the failed jobs table

Comment: actually the problem is that jobs never fail

Comment: You mean it stucks in the process?

Comment: Try With database driver

Comment: I tried and nothing changes . it just says "Processing" and and it never fails

Comment: I'm going crazy ,it neither fails nor processes :|

Comment: Check This
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354331/when-using-laravel-queue-job-processing-getting-stuck